# Get signed certificate from IDP

Tags: authentication, salesforce, saml

With Salesforce as SP and a third party IDP (could be any one), I need the Salesforce access token. I have IDP credentials and using them can I generate the Salesforce session Id silently i.e. as a background process?

I have the SAML assertion but that needs to be signed by IDP so that Salesforce can authenticate that but I dont have IDP private key. Is there a way that IDP's can provide me a signed assertion which I can use to post to Salesforce and generate a session Id?

Comment: I don't understand - you say you have a SAML Assertion, but it isn't signed? What IdP is issuing Assertions that are not signed?

Comment: As per my understanding IDP sends a signed assertion directly to Salesforce. I am trying to fetch that signed assertion so that I can directly send a post to Salesforce and fetch the Salesforce session Id. May be a security threat but trying if that is possible.

Comment: Do you want this one time, or as part of a solution you're building? It's possible to capture the assertion on the way through the browser, but that's not something you'd do in production!